# Could cosmic rays be used for power on Mars?

Tags: radiation, space-travel

Most studies of radiation levels of Mars that I can easily find focus on it as a hazard for potential human visitors. As such, a figure in rads or Sieverts is provided, which lumps together all of the types of radiation. The reason for the much higher radiation levels on Mars is always reported as its lack of magnetic field, but this effect is exacerbated by the minimal atmosphere which leaves little to absorb the radiation.

Assuming the lack of magnetic field is the more significant factor, and since the path of light is not affected by the presence of a magnetic field, that would mean that the vast difference in radiation levels comes from an increase in high-energy charged particles reaching the surface of Mars from space. That sounds to me like a potential non-trivial source of current, and hence energy, for anyone with a few conducting coils to hand. If you set up a weak magnetic field to separate the charges and enough protons (or even alpha radiation) reach the surface, you might even have a useful trickle of light elements out of this set-up.

Is this viable? How much (or, more likely, how little) energy could you expect to collect by setting up some coils on the surface of mars?

Comment: Sure; why not? After gathering all those cosmic rays using a vast collector you could just about fry an ant. With your 1 km$^2$ area collector you could heat up a cup of coffee in about 5 hours/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[No, it does not make much sense](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/27133/cosmic-rays-can-be-new-energy-source). The intensity of cosmic rays in free space is about $5\cdot 10^{-5}$ W/m$^2$; less so on Mars. Meanwhile the solar irradiance on Mars is 586.2 W/m$^2$, a hundred million times more.
Keeping coils with magnetic fields will cost you energy, while photovoltaics are nearly passive elements. So solar panels win.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't the reason that the intensity of general cosmic rays is lower in the solar system because of solar wind? That's what I was expecting to be the source of the radiation, not just extragalactic cosmic rays. Or is it just that the Sun's magnetic field blocks more incoming rays than being in the Sun's vicinity provides?

Comment: @MorganRogers  at the orbit of the earth the solar wind :  a density   of  about  5  electrons  and  ions  $cm^3$  https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1029/GM125p0073.